# How should I pass extra parameters through email headers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a support application (https://www.cloudmailin.com) which would allow customers to mail to support@myapp.com and reply to this same email address. When I send the headers with the email and customer replay to same email address, I can't get back these extra headers in parameters. Please help

Reference :- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.3/action_mailer_basics.html

See this point -
2.3.1 Custom Headers

mailers/arriva_drive_mailer.rb

```
class ArriveDriveMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_notification_to_participant(note_content, participant)
    @participant = participant
    @note_content = note_content
    headers {"X-Spam" => 'demo', "X-Special" => 'example'}
    mail(from: Settings.mail.default_url_options.support_email, to: @participant.email, subject: t('mailer.participant.subject.welcome'))
  end
```

Parameters after replay

```
 Parameters: {"headers"=>{"Received"=>["by mail-we0-f171.google.com with SMTP id p10so9411954wes.30 for <4ba24d147e70d4016a69@cloudmailin.net>; Mon, 11 Aug 2014 22:27:23 -0700", "by 10.216.3.10 with HTTP; Mon, 11 Aug 2014 22:27:23 -0700"], "Date"=>"Tue, 12 Aug 2014 10:57:23 +0530", "From"=>"parthiv patel <parthiv.savani@gmail.com>", "To"=>"4ba24d147e70d4016a69@cloudmailin.net", "Message-ID"=>"<CALiaHo7D4e+qQOqVNZrZjgL=Lufv_kMx4sVCxREr-_514W6ONw@mail.gmail.com>", "In-Reply-To"=>"<CALiaHo7sdFmJvr4Gq-Ra5fQUW63_B44jArYASYTR9JZ6uVAmAw@mail.gmail.com>", "References"=>"<53e9a37d64679_c722578fd6239511@BoTree.mail> <CALiaHo7sdFmJvr4Gq-Ra5fQUW63_B44jArYASYTR9JZ6uVAmAw@mail.gmail.com>", "Subject"=>"Re: Welcome to DRIVE", "Mime-Version"=>"1.0", "Content-Type"=>"multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7bf10ade272f91050067edc8", "DKIM-Signature"=>"v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=20120113; h=mime-version:in-reply-to:references:date:message-id:subject:from:to :content-type; bh=rBXuQHKQWJsAJB+P1ScZBAA7wVxRyNr9hWdjOFeiSPo=; b=CVIk/K2/jFuHPNoKdLzOu3f8Idbjwv/qt9lptSLra1vyI8PyjzgY2wBJPY0ivno2VB OwhFh+zCA0cShjEZy39vRR9DQ6YdHPCBZJroAEojMsqefFnsWI5Ykx+VB8ognGmQk5/b +Q9DxIPeqVeqekoGCfSmxvtAOf4PJFAtMH9ddGiP5p8o2tOIr5nRElBPH6bLGhryEhmr xpsIw58Z4j/2IsgngXQNYCbt3oP6DkfA9pNeMit5FvCUm4xFopCGJAGEYWyCifWZ4NLR oiMLjUwAvGF5r5Ua+evDPwOluNMXIPsrPKDw8qyjPpNUqVUr/MoLegqXVWK+1wEML4FS 6xdw==", "X-Received"=>"by 10.194.110.7 with SMTP id hw7mr2645299wjb.38.1407821243951; Mon, 11 Aug 2014 22:27:23 -0700 (PDT)"}, "envelope"=>{"to"=>"4ba24d147e70d4016a69@cloudmailin.net", "recipients"=>["4ba24d147e70d4016a69@cloudmailin.net"], "from"=>"parthiv.savani@gmail.com", "helo_domain"=>"mail-we0-f171.google.com", "remote_ip"=>"74.125.82.171", "spf"=>{"result"=>"neutral", "domain"=>"gmail.com"}}, "plain"=>"Dsdsdsd sdsssssssssssss ds\n\n\nOn Tue, Aug 12, 2014 at 10:51 AM, parthiv patel <parthiv.savani@gmail.com>\nwrote:\n\n> dfsdf sdf sdf sdf df dfd f dfd fdf\n>\n>\n> On Tue, Aug 12, 2014 at 10:47 AM, <demo4582@gmail.com> wrote:\n>\n>>  Dear Jignesh\n>>\n>> Following are the contents of the note you have been tagged in:\n>>\n>> dddddddddddddddd\n>>\n>>  Kind Regards\n>>\n>> The DRIVE Programme Team\n>>\n>\n>\n", "html"=>"<div dir=\"ltr\">Dsdsdsd sdsssssssssssss ds<br></div><div class=\"gmail_extra\"><br><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\">On Tue, Aug 12, 2014 at 10:51 AM, parthiv patel <span dir=\"ltr\">&lt;<a href=\"mailto:parthiv.savani@gmail.com\" target=\"_blank\">parthiv.savani@gmail.com</a>&gt;</span> wrote:<br>\n<blockquote class=\"gmail_quote\" style=\"margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex\"><div dir=\"ltr\">dfsdf sdf sdf sdf df dfd f dfd fdf<br></div><div class=\"HOEnZb\"><div class=\"h5\"><div class=\"gmail_extra\">\n<br><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\">On Tue, Aug 12, 2014 at 10:47 AM,  <span dir=\"ltr\">&lt;<a href=\"mailto:demo4582@gmail.com\" target=\"_blank\">demo4582@gmail.com</a>&gt;</span> wrote:<br>\n<blockquote class=\"gmail_quote\" style=\"margin:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex\"><u></u>\n\n  \n    \n  \n  <div>\n    <h3>Dear Jignesh</h3>\n    <input name=\"notification_tyle\" value=\"notes\" type=\"hidden\">\n    <p>\n      Following are the contents of the note you have been tagged in:\n    </p>\n    <p>\n      dddddddddddddddd\n    </p>\n    <br>\n    <p>\n      Kind Regards\n    </p>\n    <p>\n      The DRIVE Programme Team\n    </p>\n  </div>\n\n</blockquote></div><br></div>\n</div></div></blockquote></div><br></div>\n", "reply_plain"=>"Dsdsdsd sdsssssssssssss ds", "attachments"=>nil, "participant_attachment"=>{}}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the docs that you linked to that says a mail client is supposed to include your custom headers when creating a reply. Its been forever since I worked with email on this level, but I doubt that is part of the standards. Mail clients generate standard email headers and that's it. Given that, you might want to rethink the approach you're taking (or at least try replying with more than one email client).

Comment: @SunilD.- The cloudmailin service is only for as a callback when I replay from my gmail account.but I'm not use this service for send the email. I'm just use this service for replay only. My question is how to send the extra headers with email using rails only not using cloudmailin service. Got it??